# Loop in a list of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list, for-loop

For now, I have this code, and it works, but I know that I can use a `for` loop to make the code more efficient and readable. However, I'm struggling with the implementation.

```
first = pd.DataFrame()
second = pd.DataFrame()
third = pd.DataFrame()
fourth = pd.DataFrame()
fiveth = pd.DataFrame()


first['1PLetra'] = letras
first = pd.merge(first, posicao[['1PLetra', '1P']], on='1PLetra', how='left')
first = first.fillna(0)

second['2PLetra'] = letras
second = pd.merge(second, posicao[['2PLetra', '2P']], on='2PLetra', how='left')
second = second.fillna(0)

third['3PLetra'] = letras
third = pd.merge(third, posicao[['3PLetra', '3P']], on='3PLetra', how='left')
third = third.fillna(0)

fourth['4PLetra'] = letras
fourth = pd.merge(fourth, posicao[['4PLetra', '4P']], on='4PLetra', how='left')
fourth = fourth.fillna(0)

fiveth['5PLetra'] = letras
fiveth = pd.merge(fiveth, posicao[['5PLetra', '5P']], on='5PLetra', how='left')
fiveth = fiveth.fillna(0)
```

I've tried the following, but with no success:

```
list_df = [first, second, third, fourth, fiveth]

for i, df in enumerate(list_df, start=1):
    col_name = f"{i}PLetra"
    df[col_name] = letras
    df = pd.merge(df, posicao[[col_name, f"{i}P"]], on=col_name, how='left')
    df = df.fillna(0)
```

For anyone willing to help, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're overwriting `df` in each loop:

```
for i, df in enumerate(list_df, start=1):
```

Use another list to collect the outputs:

```
list_df = [first, second, third, fourth, fiveth]
out = []

for i, df in enumerate(list_df, start=1):
    col_name = f"{i}PLetra"
    df = df.copy() # avoid mutating original df
    df[col_name] = letras
    df = pd.merge(df, posicao[[col_name, f"{i}P"]], on=col_name, how='left')
    df = df.fillna(0)
    out.append(df)
```

Or, if you want to mutate the list:

```
list_df = [first, second, third, fourth, fiveth]

for i, df in enumerate(list_df):
    col_name = f"{i+1}PLetra"
    df[col_name] = letras
    df = pd.merge(df, posicao[[col_name, f"{i+1}P"]], on=col_name, how='left')
    list_df[i] = df.fillna(0)
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer, but I dont know if I understand correctly. 

I tried the first solution and returned the following error:

KeyError: "['2PLetra', '3PLetra', '4PLetra', '5PLetra'] not found in axis"

The second solution returned the same output of my loop, but it's not giving the same result of my "no loop" code.

Comment: @Lucas please provide minimal examples of `first`/`second`/`letras`/`posicao` for clarity

Comment: `first`/`second`/ and so on are just new dataframes that are used as temporary dataframes to insert missing letter from the alphabet. I concatenate all these 5 dataframes afterwards to have a single one having the data I need.

`letras` is a list with all letters from the alphabet
`posicao` is a dataframe containing the data I will use, but with missing letters.